# Using RateHelper (bootstrapping) and Speed up in Quantlib Python

Tags: python, quantlib, bootstrapping

I am wondering whether it is possible somehow to speed up my script using ratehelpers/bootstrapping. I am creating for every days a new ratehelper. Is there a way building up just once the ratehelper and then bootstrap day by day? If yes how would an example look like?

***Update:***

My Data:

> ```
> fact_date product_type    fra_start_period    maturity    tenor   quote   currency
> 2015-02-09    Deposit 0D  1D      0.081   JPY
> 2015-02-09    OIS     1W      0.0713  JPY
> 2015-02-09    OIS     3W      0.0663  JPY
> 2015-02-09    OIS     1M      0.0656  JPY
> 2015-02-09    OIS     2M      0.0613  JPY
> 2015-02-09    OIS     3M      0.06    JPY
> 2015-02-09    OIS     10M     0.05    JPY
> 2015-02-09    OIS     12M     0.0494  JPY
> 2015-02-09    OIS     5Y      0.1563  JPY
> 2015-02-09    OIS     6Y      0.2025  JPY
> 2015-02-09    OIS     7Y      0.2481  JPY
> 2015-02-09    OIS     10Y     0.3806  JPY
> 2015-02-09    OIS     15Y     0.6888  JPY
> 2015-02-09    OIS     20Y     0.965   JPY
> 2015-02-09    OIS     25Y     1.1081  JPY
> 2015-02-09    OIS     30Y     1.1831  JPY
> 2015-02-10    Deposit 0D  1D      0.074   JPY
> 2015-02-10    OIS     1W      0.0725  JPY
> 2015-02-10    OIS     3W      0.0688  JPY
> 2015-02-10    OIS     1M      0.0681  JPY
> 2015-02-10    OIS     2M      0.0625  JPY
> 2015-02-10    OIS     3M      0.0606  JPY
> 2015-02-10    OIS     10M     0.0531  JPY
> 2015-02-10    OIS     12M     0.0525  JPY
> 2015-02-10    OIS     5Y      0.1719  JPY
> 2015-02-10    OIS     6Y      0.2244  JPY
> 2015-02-10    OIS     7Y      0.2744  JPY
> 2015-02-10    OIS     10Y     0.4169  JPY
> 2015-02-10    OIS     15Y     0.7269  JPY
> 2015-02-10    OIS     20Y     1.0044  JPY
> 2015-02-10    OIS     25Y     1.1475  JPY
> 2015-02-10    OIS     30Y     1.2225  JPY
> ```

My Code:

```
import QuantLib as ql
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

def Convert(Period):
    unit =[]
    if Period[-1:] == 'D':
        unit = ql.Days
    elif Period[-1:] == 'M':
        unit = ql.Months
    elif Period[-1:] == 'W':
        unit = ql.Weeks
    elif Period[-1:] == 'Y':
        unit = ql.Years
    period_object = ql.Period(int(Period[:-1]), unit)
    return period_object

def qlStr2periodNumber(Period):
    if Period[-1:] == "D":
        period_unit = int(Period[:1])
    elif Period[-1:] == 'M':
        period_unit = int(Period[:1])
    elif Period[-1:] == 'W':
        period_unit = int(Period[:1])
    elif Period[-1:] == 'Y':
        period_unit = int(Period[:1])
    elif Period == '':
        period_unit = int(0)
    else:
        raise Exception('(qlStr2periodNumber) Period'+ Period + 'not recognized!')
    return period_unit

def Datetime2ql(date):
    dates = ql.DateParser.parseFormatted(date,'%Y-%m-%d')
    return dates

def ql2Datetime(date):
    dates = dt.datetime(date.year(), date.month(), date.dayOfMonth())
    return dates

Index_OIS = ql.OvernightIndex("Tonar", 2, ql.JPYCurrency(), ql.Japan(), ql.Actual365Fixed())

data = pd.read_csv('C:/Book1.csv').fillna('')

quote_map = {}
helpers = []

for product_type, fra_start_period, maturity, quote in zip(data.product_type, data.fra_start_period, data.maturity, data.quote): 
    quotes = ql.SimpleQuote(quote/100)
    if product_type == 'Deposit':
        helper = ql.DepositRateHelper(ql.QuoteHandle(quotes),
                                      ql.Period(2,ql.Days),
                                      qlStr2periodNumber(fra_start_period),
                                      ql.Japan(),
                                      ql.ModifiedFollowing,
                                      False,
                                      ql.Actual365Fixed()                                      
                                      )
    elif product_type == 'OIS':
        helper = ql.OISRateHelper(2,
                                  Convert(maturity),
                                  ql.QuoteHandle(quotes),
                                  Index_OIS)

    helpers.append(helper)        

    quote_map[(product_type,fra_start_period,maturity)] = quotes

curve = ql.PiecewiseCubicZero(0, ql.Japan(), helpers, ql.Actual365Fixed())

for current_date in zip(data.fact_date):
    time = current_date[0]
    ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = Datetime2ql(str(time))
    for row in data:
        quote_map[(product_type, fra_start_period, maturity, quote)].setValue(quote)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to reduce the number of objects you'll create; whether this will speed up your calculations depend on how much time is taken by their creation and how much is taken by the actual bootstrapping.  In any case:

1. When you create your rate helpers, make sure you're passing quote objects and not simple numbers; that is, something like

   ```
   q1 = SimpleQuote(0.0125)
   h1 = DepositRateHelper(QuoteHandle(q1), index)
   ```

   and not

   ```
   h1 = DepositRateHelper(0.0125, index)
   ```
2. when you create your curve, don't specify its reference date explicitly; instead, specify it as a number of days (possibly 0) from the global evaluation date; that is, something like

   ```
   curve = PiecewiseFlatForward(0, UnitedStates(), helpers, day_counter)
   ```

   if you want the reference date to equal the evaluation date, or

   ```
   curve = PiecewiseFlatForward(2, UnitedStates(), helpers, day_counter)
   ```

   if you want it to start spot.  This way, the reference date of the curve will move when the evaluation date changes.
3. Now you're setup.  When you want to change to a new date, you'll write

   ```
   Settings.instance().evaluationDate = new_today
   ```

   and for each quote,

   ```
   q1.setValue(new_value)
   ```

   the curve will detect the changes and recalculate accordingly.

In pseudocode, the idea would be to have a setup like:

```
quote_map = {}
helpers = []
for type, fra_start_date, maturity in ...  # extract unique helper data
    quote = SimpleQuote(...)
    if type == 'Deposit':
        helper = ...
    else:
        ...
    helpers.append(helper)
    quote_map[(type,fra_start_date,maturity)] = quote
curve = PiecewiseCubicZero(2, Japan(), helpers, day_counter)
```

and then the loop over the dates:

```
for current_date in ...
    # Don't build stuff, just change date and quotes
    Settings.instance().evaluationDate = current_date
    for row in ...
        quote_map[(type,fra_start_date,maturity)].setValue(value)
    # now the curve is updated and you can use it
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint. Somehow I am still struggeling concerning the helper. I updated my question with an example since not just the quotes but also the maturity is my problem. How can I handle this because having a quote object how do I link the proper maturity to it? Maybe you can show it based on my example above? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that's a problem. You're passing a tenor (2 years, for instance), not a hard-coded maturity. When the evaluation date changes, the helper recalculates its maturity date as well.  Thus, you can create your objects outside the loop (one helper per quoted tenor, and a curve that doesn't take a hard-coded date; see my point 2 above) and then loop over the dates in your data and set evaluation date and quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried the way and updated the code above. Somehow it fails:  'NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_QuoteHandle'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    Handle< Quote >::Handle(boost::shared_ptr< Quote > const &)
    Handle< Quote >::Handle()'

Comment: You're passing to `QuoteHandle` the whole list of quotes, not just the quote you last created.

Comment: Now I got it. Hope the updated code above is the one you mean how to handle it.

Comment: You're still creating helpers at each date.  You can create them (and the curve) just once, outside the `for current_date` loop.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update. I tried to update my code, somehow the second part from your pseudocode is not clear for me. I tried the pseudocode suggestion but receive the follwoing error:  'quote_map[(product_type, fra_start_period, maturity, quote)].setValue(quote)
KeyError: ('SWAP', '', '30Y', 1.4275)'. Seems that I don't fully understand your pseudocode?

Comment: My code didn't have the quote value in the key.  The idea was to save the quotes in a map so that you can retrieve the correct one for the helper and set its value.  The helper is identified by its type and its start or maturity.  This said, if you will need to maintain and extend the code, and if you don't have hard time requirements, you might consider sticking with your version of the code.  It's simpler, and you know precisely what it does.

Comment: (Also, Stack Exchange is not the right place for extended discussions like this.  You might want to take this to the QuantLib mailing list.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will take it to the QuantLib Mailing List